# Password not getting encrypted when I update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Being a newb to python I am not quite sure why I am getting inconsistent results. 
I register a user and the password in my table ends up being the hashed version. When the user updates his password, the password in the table ends up being the unhashed version. Obviously, I want the hashed version. What am I doing wrong? (I am using SQLAlchemy and mysql if that matters.)

I have the following:

```
def hash_password(password):
    blah, blah, blah # hash my password here
    return hashed_password

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    email = Column('email')
    _password = Column('password')

    def _get_password(self):
        return self._password

    def _set_password(self, password):
        self._password = hash_password(password)
    password = property(_get_password, _set_password)
    password = synonym('_password', descriptor=password)

    def __init__(self, password="", email=""):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    @classmethod
    def register(cls, email, password):
        return DBSession.add(User(email=email,password=password)) # this correctly hashes the password

    @classmethod
    def update(cls, email, password):
        return DBSession.query(cls).filter(cls.email == email).update({'password': password}) #password ends up being the unhashed password
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is the way that you are updating the password via your `User.update` method. This method is skipping the ORM entirely and updating the row directly in the database. It should be obvious that the code to hash the password will not run when you do this. The `User` model that you pasted is just fine and similar to what I use. You need to use it though. This means that to update a password you should load the user, and set their password.

```
user = DBSession.query(User).filter_by(email=email).first()
if user:
    user.password = new_password
```

and later when the transaction is committed things will be the way you expect.

Comment: What I'm getting at by my answer is that you should stop using the `User.update` method. It's not a good pattern for interacting with your database via SQLAlchemy.

Comment: You are right. I accepted the other answer because I got it working but I never felt comfortable that it was the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You should store password hash in database, so field of your model must contain hash value, not raw password. To set password, you should use methods, that makes hashing and set hash to instance. To check, if password is correct, you should hash user-defined password and compare result with hash stored in your instance. Yo will not be able to decode password from hash - it's unsecure.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    email = Column('email', String(80))
    password = Column('password', String(80))

    def set_password(raw_password):
        self.password = hash(raw_password)

    def check_password(raw_password):
        return self.password == hash(raw_password)
```